# Is the time complexity of the following snippet O(n^2)?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I was wondering if the time complexity of the following code snippet is `O(n^2)`:

```
class Solution {
public:

    int numSquares(int n) {
        if(n<=0)
            return 0;

        vector<int> dp(n+1, INT_MAX);
        dp[0]=0;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            for(int j=1; j*j<=i; j++) {
                //+1 because you are adding the current `j`
                dp[i]=min(dp[i], dp[i-j*j]+1);
            }
        }

        return dp[n];
    }
};
```

I am not sure because in the inner loop, we are checking for perfect squares less than `i`, which would be very less in comparison to `i` (and I think so less, that they can be assumed to be constant).  In this case then, the complexity would be just `O(n)`.  So, can I say that the complexity is `O(n)` or is it `O(n^2)`?

Note: The code snippet is a solution to a question from [LeetCode.com](https://leetcode.com/) which apparently has a collection of interview questions.

Comment: I would say complexity is `O(n √n)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, two questions - `i`. how `O(n √n)`?; and `ii`. how did you insert that square root symbol?

Comment: Outer loop is `O(N)`, inner loop is `O(0.5 √N)`. Since there is no condition to exit either loop early, you simply multiply them together to get the total complexity, and drop the coefficient, since those don't belong in big-O. And the shortcut for `√` on Mac is `ALT+V`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The outer loop is `O(N)`.
The inner loop is `O(sqrt(i))`.

The sum will be:

```
1 + sqrt(2) + ... + sqrt(N)
```

It's greater than `O(N)` but is less than `O(N^2)`.

Without going into a very accurate computation of the above sum, I would say, it's close to `O(N*sqrt(N))`.

**Update**

From http://ramanujan.sirinudi.org/Volumes/published/ram09.pdf, the above sum is:

```
C1 + (2.0/3)*N*SQRT(N) + (1.0/2)*SQRT(N) + ....
```

Comment: Wow!  Didn't even think about that.  Could you please point out how `sqrt(i)`?

Comment: It's not "close to", it is. As `N -> ∞`, the timing of the function increases proportionally to `N √N`

Comment: Also, this means that it's technically also `O(n^2)`, and `O(n^3)`, and `O(2^n)`, etc.

Comment: @UmedhSinghBundela, `(j*j <= i) ` is equivalent to `j <=sqrt(i)`.